# getting all tables containing a certain word

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I would like to `SELECT` all table names that contain a certain word.

For example I have these tables in my database:

**test**
**test_trash**
**table**
**table_trash**
**users**
**changelog**

So, I only want to select all the tables that contain _trash
Is this possible with PDO?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `SHOW TABLES like '%word%'`  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-tables.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure that is possible:

```
SHOW TABLES LIKE '%_trash%';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SHOW TABLES LIKE '%\_trash%';
```

(The backslash is needed to make `_` be the character, not the wildcard.)

Comment: I didn't have any problems, worked without the backslash too!

Comment: That is coincidence!  Test with `SELECT "_trash" LIKE '%_trash%', "Xtrash" LIKE '%\_trash%';` -- this gives TRUE, FALSE.  Do you want "Xtrash" to be included in your list?

Comment: If I use your query I get errors because of the double quotes around _trash and Xtrash. And this query is not working because this `SELECT` is trying to select columns, not table names. I appreciate your help tho!

Comment: What context is having trouble with double-quotes?  Change my examples to single quotes.  In MySQL's SQL syntax, _most_ places are equally happy with single- versus double-quotes.

Comment: Thanks that helped me